# os.walk in Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, os.walk

I'm trying to walk through directories of audio files in order to print out their data into an Excel sheet. Right now I'm only able to access the files in the root folder - I am stuck on accessing the files of in any subfolders. When I 'print(audio_file)' before the line 'if os.path.isfile(audio_file):' it loops through all the files in all directories, however I have the 'isfile' line so the code below only looks at the files. I'm stuck at this point and not sure what to do.

The os.walk loop is at the bottom of the code:

```
import openpyxl, os, wave, time, datetime
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from datetime import datetime

os.chdir('c:\\Users\\Sonorityscape\\Desktop\\audiofiles')

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

sheet = wb['Sheet']

headings = {'A1' : 'File Name',
            'B1' : 'Relative Path',
            'C1' : 'File Size',
            'D1' : 'Date of Creation',
            'E1' : 'File Length (hr:mn:sc.msc)',
            'F1' : 'Channels',
            'G1' : 'Sample Rate',
            'H1' : 'Bit Depth'}

cell_widths = {'A' : 30,
               'B' : 40,
               'C' : 11.5,
               'D' : 19,
               'E' : 25.75,
               'F' : 10.5,
               'G' : 13.5,
               'H' : 10.5}

for k, v in headings.items():
    sheet[k].value = v
    sheet[k].font = Font(bold = True, name = 'Calibri', size = 12)

for k, v in cell_widths.items():
    sheet.column_dimensions[k].width = float(v)

def file_info(file_name, folder_name, file_size, date_time, col_file, col_folder, col_size, col_time):
    sheet.cell(row = r, column = col_file).value = file_name
    sheet.cell(row = r, column = col_folder).value = folder_name
    sheet.cell(row = r, column = col_size).value = str(round((file_size / 2**20), 3)) + ' MB'
    sheet.cell(row = r, column = col_time).value = date_time

def sample_rate(frames, col):
    frame_rate = w.getframerate()
    file_length = (frames / frame_rate)
    length_milliseconds = str(round((frames / frame_rate), 3)) 
    sheet.cell(row = r, column = col).value = str(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(file_length))) + '.' + length_milliseconds[-3:]  


def wave_info(channels, frame_rate, bit_depth, col_chan, col_fr, col_bit):
    sheet.cell(row = r, column = col_chan).value = channels
    sheet.cell(row = r, column = col_fr).value = str(frame_rate) + ' Hz'
    sheet.cell(row = r, column = col_bit).value = str(bit_depth * 8) + ' bit' 

r = 3

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('c:\\Users\\Sonorityscape\\Desktop\\audiofiles'):
    for audio_file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(audio_file):

            w = wave.open(audio_file)

            file_name = os.path.basename(audio_file)
            folder_name = os.path.relpath('c:\\audiofiles\\' + audio_file, 'c:\\desktop')
            file_size = os.path.getsize(audio_file)
            time_created = os.path.getctime(audio_file)
            date_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(time_created).strftime('%b. %d, %Y, %H:%M:%S')

            frames = w.getnframes()
            if w.getnchannels() == 2:
                channels = 'Stereo'
            else:
                channels = 'Mono'
            frame_rate = w.getframerate()
            bit_depth = w.getsampwidth()

            file_info(file_name, folder_name, file_size, date_time, 1, 2, 3, 4)
            sample_rate(frames, 5)
            wave_info(channels, frame_rate, bit_depth, 6, 7, 8)

            w.close()

            r += 1

wb.save('c:\\users\\sonorityscape\\desktop\\audiofilesexcel.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify this line:

```
if os.path.isfile(audio_file):
```

to

```
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root,audio_file)):
```

as audio_file is only a string of filename, you should add the abs path to the file.
You changed current path with code:

```
os.chdir('c:\\Users\\Sonorityscape\\Desktop\\audiofiles')
```

That's why you can get the files in root dir but not sub folders.

Comment: I was trying this solution before but it was not able to locate the file in the next sub folder saying: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'audiofile.wav'

Comment: I think you need to post more information about you exception. This works for me.for root,dirs, files in os.walk(path):
 for f in files:
  print os.path.join(root,f) here is the output:C:\Users\Snowy\Documents\smart-log\io_bench
C:\Users\Snowy\Documents\smart-log\log.c
C:\Users\Snowy\Documents\smart-log\log.h
C:\Users\Snowy\Documents\smart-log\sub1\1.tar.gz
C:\Users\Snowy\Documents\smart-log\sub1\sub2\insub2.txt
C:\Users\Snowy\Documents\smart-log\sub1\sub2\sub3\insub3.txt

Comment: The complete message is: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sonorityscape\Desktop\practice.py", line 60, in <module>
    w = wave.open(audio_file)
  File "C:\Users\Sonorityscape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wave.py", line 510, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "C:\Users\Sonorityscape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wave.py", line 160, in __init__
    f = builtins.open(f, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'four.wav'

Comment: here  w = wave.open(audio_file) you still need to add the abs file path to the file.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I got it working when I added the os.path.join to all places with the audio_file variable.